# Mongodb php backup collections

Tags: php, mongodb, backup, restore

I have a problem, my code does not work exactly as I want. I need to create a backup and restore. And that is my problem; My new collection is not identical.
Wrong data form:

[image]

**My backup**

```
$db = $m->$dbname;  
  try{
$backup1 = $db->people->find();
$text1=json_encode(iterator_to_array($backup1));
$people = 'people.txt';
if ($text1 ){
file_put_contents($people, $text1,  LOCK_EX);
echo 'complete';
}
else echo 'error';
```

**My restore**

```
$db = $m->$dbname;  
  try{   
$collection = $db->people1; 
$file = file_get_contents('people.txt', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
if ($file){
$file = json_decode($file);
foreach ($file as $id => $item) {
   $collection->insert($item);
}
echo 'Restore complete';
}
else echo 'Error';
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you wan't to do this from PHP? You can just use mongodump

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mongodump` and `mongorestore` — [Back Up and Restore with MongoDB Tools](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/backup-and-restore-tools/)